# Excel copy/paste formula with INDEX or OFFSET (relative reference)

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste, offset

Normally when you copy and paste formulas into different cells, column and row references are relative by default unless you add the '$' symbol, which makes them absolute.

But with INDEX and OFFSET, when I copy and paste, the column and row references seem to be absolute only. Is there a way to make them relative?

A have a named range and I want to find the sum of each row in that range. I'm using:

```
=SUM(INDEX(Q1UnitTotals,1,0))
```

which works fine, but when I copy and paste, it does not change the row number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the `1` is a value, not a range reference.  To make it dynamic you need to make it a range reference.  This can be done with `ROW()`

If the `Sum` formula is in row `1` use

```
=SUM(INDEX(Q1UnitTotals,ROW(),0))
```

If the `Sum` formula is *not* in row `1` use

```
=SUM(INDEX(Q1UnitTotals,ROW(A1),0))
```